# How can I force node.js to be case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, apache2, case-sensitive

We have a AngularJS project locally running on node.js. We published on an Apache server and noticed that Angular includes do not differ between upper and lower case letters as long as it is running locally. At the Apache the include cannot be loaded.

Anyone any idea where to configure this case sensitivity issue?

Comment: This sounds more like an OS problem. Are you using the same OS locally as the Apache server is running on? What OS _are_ you using locally and for the server?

Comment: This has nothing to do with AngularJS. IMO there is no solution other than not using Windows and/or having good e2e-tests running on non-Windows servers.

Comment: (And I'm not clear what the connection between NodeJs and Apache is either)